# Foundation sass rem-calc error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I use Foundaton 5.0.2 gem, but when I try to load the view, I get the next error message:

Sass::UnitConversionError: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'em'

So I suppose that this is something with the "rem-calc" function there, but I don't know how to fix it...

My gems list is:

- sass (3.2.14),
- compass (0.12.3),
- foundation (1.0.4)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your _settings.scss. There must be this lines:

```
$row-width: rem-calc(1000);
$column-gutter: rem-calc(30);
$total-columns: 12;
```

If you wish to modify them or just solve this problem, try to comment them out and specify $rem-base with you font size in px:

```
$base-font-size: 14px;
$rem-base: $base-font-size;
```